# React: this.setState() не работает

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Учу реакт. Хочу поменять в функции значение tags в state а потом отправить post запрос (по нажатию на кнопку). Кнопка:

```
...
 this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit(e).bind(this);
...

 <button className="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="button" onClick={this.onSubmit}>
      Сохранить
 </button>
```

Код:

```
 handleSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();
const abc = this.tags.split(' ');
this.setState({ tags: abc })
if (this.isNotEmptyStates) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/landmarks',
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(this.state),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function () {
      alert("OK!");
      location.reload();
    },
    async: false,
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert('some error');
    }
  })
} else { alert("Не все поля заполненны") };
}
```

tags.split в abc работает, однако в this.setState({tags:abc}) - не работает, строка всё также остаётся.

Допустим на момент вызова в tags находится строка "hello world". 
После вызова функции в сonsole log обозначенным звёздочкой будет 
выведен массив ["hello","world"]. Однако в this.setState ничего не поменяется. Так и останется "hello world"

UPD:

Делал и через временные переменные и через callback - результат один и тот же: обновление стейта происходит после выполнения функции.

Comment: `tags: ""` с чего же он окажется abc?

Comment: в дополнение - setState  - выполняется  асинхронно..и вызов первого еще не отработал -вызывается уже второй. Ключевое слово здесь — асинхронно. Обновление DOM не происходит мгновенно при вызове this.setState. React поочередно обновляет элементы, чтобы максимально эффективно обновить DOM.

Comment: @СергейПетрашко а как сделать так чтобы это работало не асинхронно ?

Comment: никак. опиши более подробно зачем ты так делаешь. тебе помогут решить эту проблему

Comment: @СергейПетрашко есть кнопка по нажатию на которую необходимо отправить post запрос на сервер, предварительно изменив state

Answer (score 2):

Он меняет локальный стейт верно, то есть в конце стейт `tags` равен `""` просто сам класс(компонент) не успевает перерендриться.

Попробуйте его вывести в методе `render()`:

```
render() {

   const { tags } = this.state;

   console.log(tags, 'tags')

}
```

> И в дальнейшем если вы хотите манипулировать содержанием стейтов в
>   одном объекте, лучше всего делать временные переменные, а в стейт
>   записывать окончательный результат

Если нужно изменить стейт по нажатию на кнопку -

```
<button onClick={() => this.setState({tags: 'tags'})}>go</button>
```

Или если вы должны как то изменить содержимое передающейся переменной, то -

```
editState = (params) => {

      const { params } = this.state;

      const tags = params.split(' ');

      this.setState({tags})

};

<button onClick={() => this.editState(params)}>go</button>
```

Comment: Необходимо чтобы он именно в функции вызывался (при клике на кнопку)

Comment: @ГригорийСысоев В одной функции не классно использовать 2 сетстейт. Во первых сетстейт делает перерендер компонента(что можно посмотреть react dev tools) и в вашем случае он делает его 2 раза, во вторых Можно обойтись временными переменными

Comment: нужно конкретно после нажатия кнопки изменить стейт, мгновенно

Comment: @ГригорийСысоев добавил в ответ все что нужно )

Comment: попробывал - не сработало; а если использовать params, то возникает ошибка: params - не определено.

Comment: @ГригорийСысоев дополните вопрос пожалуйста кодом